# Is there a difference between Ubuntu with MATE installed after and the pre-made Ubuntu MATE edition?

Tags: 14.04, unity, suspend, desktop-environments, mate

I have two computers, one that used Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity, and another with Ubuntu MATE installed from the Ubuntu MATE website. When I installed MATE on my Unity computer, I started getting issues with waking from suspend, where I was getting a second login screen from unity. I uninstalled unity and tried a recovery kernel, but it still happens. I have none of these issues with the other laptop. this prompted me to ask: if you are going to be dedicated to a DE, is it worth installing all of Ubuntu from that DE's website, or is this just a bug? I've been using this computer for a while, and I want to make sure it will work if I reinstall because transferring all of these files will be a pain. Thanks!

Comment: When you have 2 desktop environments (DEs) in the same systems, a lot of things are duplicated. They don't always work well together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your skills level.

I have two systems:

1. previously normal Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with Unity and GNOME FlashBack, then I upgraded it to 14.04 LTS and then to 16.04 LTS. On 16.04 I installed `ubuntu-mate-desktop^` and carefully removed all GNOME and Unity stuff by hand.
2. installed as 11.04 then upgraded to 12.04 LTS with manually added MATE PPA, then upgraded to 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS. After last upgrade I removed MATE PPA and carefully removed all GNOME and Unity stuff by hand.

Both resulting 16.04 LTS systems with MATE DE going to sleep and wake up without issues.

I know small differences of my self-made MATE DE system compared to MATE-edition - I removed `ubuntu-mate-welcome` and some other stuff.

In your special case I think you should remove `gnome-screensaver` package with

```
 sudo apt-get purge gnome-screensaver
```